# OS X ssh: What HostKeyAlgorithms and Ciphers are available?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, mac-osx, centos7

I'm working on some ssh hardening in our environment. I've been following [these guidelines.](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) I'm not a crypto wizard but I generally understand my way around OS X, Linux, and UNIX based services.

I'm having a difficult time understanding why the HostKeyAlgorithms and Ciphers don't work with my OS X ssh to my sshd server configured following the guidelines mentioned above.

My first question is how can I get these supported on the client side (OS X). Do I need to compile it myself? The version noted below is the most recent homebrew version. It seems recent enough.

The example below shows a snippet of my client (OS X) configuration ~/.ssh/config What is commented out are the exact recommendations from the guidelines noted above. Most of those didn't work. What does work are the ones not commented.

My next question is more ssh specific: Where do these HostKey Algos and ciphers come from? Is there a command I can run to see what's available? 'ssh -Q [cipher|mac] doesn't work with this client.

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011

# HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
# Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
#
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having a difficult time understanding why the HostKeyAlgorithms and Ciphers don't work with my OS X ssh to my sshd server configured following the guidelines mentioned above.

Because you are using old version of OpenSSH. The `HostKeyAlgorithms` were introduced in OpenSSH 7.0p1 if I remember well. Also the `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com` cipher was introduced later than in OpenSSH 6.2.

> My next question is more ssh specific: Where do these HostKey Algos and ciphers come from? Is there a command I can run to see what's available?

You can see the supported `Ciphers` and `MACs` in the manual page for `ssh_config`. It lists also the default values.

> `ssh -Q [cipher|mac]` doesn't work with this client.

This feature was also introduced later and does not work in such old OpenSSH. You would better be with updating to recent version from brew (or somewhere else). Latest it 7.2p1 version. You can build it on your own, but there is a lot of pitfalls so I would rather depend on some distribution.

Comment: The new version of macOS Sierra includes OpenSSH 7.2 which should make things easier for you. http://goodbyecli.com/macos-sierra-beta/